# 3 clickable icons in textbox

Tags: php, html, css

I wanna have 3 clickable icons in textbox
can someone support me with this

I found this code for a single clickable icon
I tried more icons in it but is not working

```css
#form1 div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden
}

#form1 label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#form1 input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}

#form1 a {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 0 0 -32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  background: transparant;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="text">Enter text:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <a href="http://www.pmob.co.uk"><img src="/user/icos/6.gif" border="none">
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ^ He wants to put icons by using `<img>` though that's not how you do it. OP if you want to add icons in a textbox, use `:before` and `:after:`

Comment: Ovidiu do you have an example for me ???

Comment: If you want to use icons so, use pseudo selectors: before and: after and margin: 2px 0 0 -32px; remove because of this icons are overlapping.

Comment: Meraj Khan do you have a example for me ???

Answer (score 0):

How about this???

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqQfY.png)

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="text">Enter text:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <a href="http://www.url.com"><img src="/folder/img/name.png" height="20" width="20">
    </a>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
```

You can expand from here, take a look at the picture.... if thats what you want

Comment: Thanks for supporting Kiyoshi but i want them into the <input type="text"

Comment: @JanJanMolendijk do you want the icon to appear inside the text box?

Comment: @Kiyoshi Yes all 3 off them inside the textbox (at the end right)

Comment: @JanJanMolendijk Do you have any screenshot from a website that you want to do the same?

Comment: @JanJanMolendijk I have edited my answer .... please also look at the image

Comment: @Kiyoshi thanks for your support but i cant place 3 icons in the <input type="text"